# Changing Indexed Yes(No Duplicates) to Indexed Yes(Duplicates OK) Via Sql Access 2007

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have a column in Table `TimeValues` and column name is `TimeId` this field is created with constraint Indexed -- `YES(No Duplicates)`
I want to change it to Indexed -- `Yes(Duplicates OK)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Right click on your table, open the table in Design View.
[image: first]

Then select your field `TimeId` and uncheck the Primary Key button as shown. 
[image: second]

Now you can change the indexing of the field in the Field Properties.
[image: third]

Save and exit the table, done!

**UPDATE 1:**

Try this code first:

```
DROP INDEX PrimaryKey
ON TimeValues
```

Then execute query:

```
CREATE INDEX TimeId ON TimeValues (TimeId);
```

Comment: thanks for the reply but I want to do it VIA SQL Query.